# PHP convert characters

Tags: php, special-characters

I'm trying to convert this `Ã¼` to `ü` in php.

I want to get this kind of characters to correct format. this is Germany characters format. somehow the database recode is like this. but it's not a correct format.

here is my code,

```
//Germany
$text = "Italienische GemÃ¼sesuppe";
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); 
$trans_sentence = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
//correct format should be like this : Italienische Gemüsesuppe
```

But this is not working as expected.

How do i do it ?

Comment: ASCII doesn't have Umlauts. If anything, Latin-1 / utf8_decode would be an option. Better yet, use UTF-8 all around.

Comment: I found the solution, removed character encode from PDO connection 
//$this->set_charset("utf8");